# ls -axi (what does it do)?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

So I was messing around in terminal, and when i opened it, I typed `cd applications` .

Nothing bad here.

Then, I typed `ls -a\` in applications (or maybe `/`, I don't know, but it opened the `>` thing after for a multi line command.

Not remembering how to exit, I tried to type `exit` but instead typed `xi` and hit enter on my MAcBook Air. It said that it was doing something, but i tried to quit the terminal seeing it was deleting/restoring something (pls don't question my logic here).

Have no idea what it did, but when i go up in terminal, it says i typed `ls -axi`

What did this do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ls -axi` would have performed a regular directory listing, but with more contents (`-a` showing dot-files), a horizontal sort (`-x`) in columns, and with the inode number present (`-i`).

From the man page for ls:

- `-a`

  > Include directory entries whose names begin with a dot (.).

  ```
  ~ $ ls
  Desktop     Downloads  Movies  Pictures
  Documents   Library    Music   Public

  ~ $ ls -a
  .          Downloads  Pictures
  ..         Library    Public
  Desktop    Movies
  Documents  Music
  ```
- `-x`

  > The same as -C, except that the multi-column output is produced with entries sorted across, rather than down, the columns.

  - `-C`

    > Force multi-column output; this is the default when output is to a terminal.

  ```
  ~ $ ls -ax
  .          ..         Desktop
  Documents  Downloads  Library
  Movies     Music      Pictures
  Public
  ```
- `-i`

  > For each file, print the file's file serial number (inode number).

  ```
  ~ $ ls -axi
  686312 .          643912 ..         686338 Desktop
  686325 Documents  686327 Downloads  686313 Library
  686390 Movies     686333 Music      686336 Pictures
  686386 Public
  ```

Comment: @nohillside I can’t reproduce -i overriding multi-column, do you have an ls alias or something? I’ve tested on Mojave.

Comment: Interesting. I get one-column output even when running ` \ls -axi`.

Comment: Nevertheless, rolled back.

Comment: Ah, depends on terminal width (and max length of application name). If I fullscreen Terminal I get multi-column as well.

Comment: @nohillside How wide is your Terminal window and the length of the lines you’re trying to print? `ls -xi ~` if you just have the default folders in your home folder, they’re quite short and show in columns for me. I’ll add some output myself.

Comment: 114 wide, in my home folder I get three columns

Comment: In `/Applications` there are things like `The Secret of Monkey Island Special Edition.app/` which is 49 characters long. Add 13 for inode and white space, takes more than half of 114 then.

Answer (score -1):

*Have no idea what it did, but when i go up in terminal, it says i typed ls -axi*

The backslash is an escape.  Take the next character literally.  So,  It seems you type ls -a\ then pressed return  which gives you the prompt.  You must have then typed xi.  The history command doesn't remember the line continuation sequence, so you get ls -axi

My experimentation with \

```
mac $ touch hi\"there\"
mac $ ls
containsBill  containsBob   containsJoe   hi"there"
mac $ ls -la hi\"there\" 
-rw-r--r--  1 mac  staff     0B Dec 19 19:56 hi"there"
mac $ ls -la\
>  hi\"there\" 
-rw-r--r--  1 mac  staff     0B Dec 19 19:56 hi"there" 
mac $ # press up arrow to get the previous command
mac $ ls -la hi\"there\" 
-rw-r--r--  1 mac  staff     0B Dec 19 19:56 hi"there"
mac $ ls -\a\l
total 40
drwxr-xr-x    7 mac  staff   238B Dec 19 19:56 ./
drwxr-xr-x+ 143 mac  staff   4.7K Dec 16 19:32 ../
-rw-r--r--@   1 mac  staff   6.0K Dec 19 15:05 .DS_Store
-rw-r--r--@   1 mac  staff    56B Dec 19 15:11 containsBill
-rw-r--r--    1 mac  staff     4B Dec 19 15:07 containsBob
-rw-r--r--    1 mac  staff     5B Dec 19 15:08 containsJoe
-rw-r--r--    1 mac  staff     0B Dec 19 19:56 hi"there"
mac $ # press up arrow to get the previous command
mac $ ls -\a\l
```